# Community consensus on enabling a banner to warn about policy on AI-generated content?

Tags: discussion

An experiment was conducted recently to test a banner highlighting the “AI-generated content” policy on Stack Overflow. The placement of the banner showed no significant impact on answer rates; however, it did see a reduction in posts flagged for AI-generated content.

The banner on SO looked something like this:

[image]

This has been progressed to provide a functionality to allow the "AI-generated content" policy banner to be enabled on Stack Overflow and all other sites in the Stack Exchange network.

All sites in the Stack Exchange network will be able to opt in (the feature is off by default, network-wide)

Two banner text options that all sites in the Stack Exchange network can opt-in to will be offered:

- **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more
- **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more

The banner will display once users select the answer field

The “new contributor” banner will no longer be shown in the answer field

Both options have a "Learn more" link, which will point to a per-site help center article (content to be determined by community discussion)

All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again

Is UXSE interested in opting into this feature? We want to start a discussion to get community consensus on the appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that it is possible to prevent or eliminate AI generated content on UXSE. I have asked and answered many questions over the years, and I have not found the need for it. So rather than not allowing these tools in principle but not really being able to enforce it, I would prefer that users cite the tools like they cite the sources or references for their answers.

There is the possibility that the use of these tools can improve the quality of questions and answers, but I would prefer these to be provided by the platform.

I don't think it will make too much difference to how we have been moderating on the site one way or another, but as usual, we would like to hear from the community on any decisions or ideas that can have a potential benefit.

Answer (score 1):

No impact on answer rates, but I wonder how disclosure might bias votes and acceptance. AI tends to have an unquestioning voice of authority, and it tends to not provide a lot of citations or visual examples (particularly useful to us). On the other hand, a post that is a hybrid of AI aggregated knowledge that is edited by a thoughtful human contibutor could provide quick answers.

I'd worry most about the signal-to-noise ratio - a bunch of generated AI that doesn't quite answer the nature of the question might drown out a thoughtful human post that doesn't sound as authoritative. And if SE becomes just a repository of AI answers, wouldn't users stop coming here and just go to AI?

Comment: +1 These are all valid points, and why I think it is important to understand what the community thinks about the potential changes. But I think that it is almost inevitable that there will be a heavy mix of human and AI-generated/assisted content, if there isn't already.